# What is the metamorphic field gradient useful for?

Tags: geology, tectonics, metamorphism

As I understand it, the metamorphic field gradient is the PT line traced out by the maximum temperature points of a series of PTt paths of rocks from the same metamorphic event.[image]

What exactly is this useful for? It seems that it doesn't really describe anything of physical significance since the $\mathrm{T_{max}}$ points can occur at different times so it doesn't represent a snapshot of the geothermal gradient at any fixed time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are entirely correct. [Todd and Engi](https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1525-1314.1997.00038.x) write:

> The mineral assemblages of rocks at the surface lie on a locus of
>   *P*–*T*-conditions… It must be stressed…does *not* imply a *P*–*T*-distribution or geotherm realized at any one time during the orogenic evolution of this area. Even assuming the *P*–*T*-values
>   reflect maximum metamorphic conditions, these were established at
>   different times in different areas…show the integrated effect of all
>   the tectonometamorphic processes…i.e. the sum of burial, heating,
>   tectonic and erosional unroofing and cooling.

Notwithstanding, the metamorphic field gradient is still useful, particularly when comparing different sets of rocks.

Each of the samples in your figure (A, B and C) is a single rock and looking at it tells you the history of this rock and this rock alone. When studying a large area (a "field") there will be many rocks, that may differ from each other in their individual *P*–*T*-path. For example, in a rock suite that is now dipping 90°, one might argue that walking 3 kilometres on the surface equals 1 kbar of pressure, equals about 3 kilometres of depth. Because of that, each sample along the transect will have experienced different temperatures, with ideally the deeper ones also being the hotter ones.

By choosing a convenient reference point (maximum temperature of an individual sample), and connecting all samples along a transect, you can get an estimate of a *P*–*T* gradient, which can approximate a geotherm (under many assumptions). The same Todd and Engi paper has this figure:

[image]

Each of the lines is based on several dozens of individual samples. Based on this representation of the data, they go on to conclude:

> The metamorphic field gradients and age determinations and consistent
>   with two stages of metamorphism. The first stage created the field
>   gradients preserved in the northern part of the field area. The second
>   thermal pulse affected only the south-eastern part of the field area.
>   This occurred at a later time, under lower pressure conditions.

Reaching those conclusions is only possible when condensing the 100 or so individual samples they used (i.e. 100 individual *P*–*T*-path loops) to what turned out to be only two metamorphic field gradients.

---

Todd, C. S. and Engi, M. (1997), Metamorphic field gradients in the Central Alps. Journal of Metamorphic Geology, 15: 513-530. doi:[10.1111/j.1525-1314.1997.00038.x](https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1525-1314.1997.00038.x)